# Unrealistic Total-Bytes-Written on SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, lifespan

At a customer's site, I have a small server with a (small) SSD. The server is in operation for about 5 years, and the SSD status looks like that, according to the manufacturer's tool:

[image: ssd toolbox screenshot]

This looks too good to be true! And, apparently, it *is* too good to be true, since the numbers don't check out:

- Today's screenshot shows that 0.58 TB have been written so far.<sup>1</sup>
- However, we perform rotating local backups of the ~10 GB worth of SQL Server databases on the server *every night* (keeping the last 3 days and deleting older backups).<sup>2</sup>

Thus, ~10 GB of new data gets written to the SSD every night, which makes ~300 GB = ~0.3 TB of data every month. This strongly contradicts the fact that only 0.58 TB have been written *over the last 5 years*.

Is the ADATA tool broken or do I have some fundamental misunderstanding of the "Total Bytes Written" metric?

---

Footnotes:

<sup>1</sup> The raw SMART data (if relevant) can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBZAe.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PiI3.png).

<sup>2</sup> Yes, I know that local backups are not a viable backup strategy. Of course, we also have off-site backups!